# why DISTINCT is needed in this Cypher query?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, distinct, aggregation

The below query is taken from neo4j movie review dataset sandbox:

```
MATCH (u:User {name: "Some User"})-[r:RATED]->(m:Movie)
WITH u, avg(r.rating) AS mean

MATCH (u)-[r:RATED]->(m:Movie)-[:IN_GENRE]->(g:Genre)
WHERE r.rating > mean

WITH u, g, COUNT(*) AS score

MATCH (g)<-[:IN_GENRE]-(rec:Movie)
WHERE NOT EXISTS((u)-[:RATED]->(rec))

RETURN rec.title AS recommendation, rec.year AS year, COLLECT(DISTINCT g.name) AS genres, SUM(score) AS sscore
ORDER BY sscore DESC LIMIT 10
```

what I can not understand is: why the `DISTINCT` keyword is required in the query's return statement?. Because the expected results from the last `MATCH` statement is something like this:

```
g1,x
g1,y
...
g2,z
g2,v
g2,m
...
gn,m
gn,b
gn,x
```

where `g1,g2,..gn` are the set of genres and `x,y,z,v,m,b...` are a set of movies (in addition there is a user and score column deleted for readability).

So according to my understanding what this query is returning: *For each movie return its genres and the sum of their scores.*

Answer (score 1):

Assumptions:

- Every `Movie` has a unique `title`. (This is required for the query to work as is.)
- Every `Genre` has a unique `name`.
- Every `Movie` has at most one `IN_GENRE` relationship to each distinct `Genre`.

Given the above assumptions, you are correct that the `DISTINCT` is not necessary. That is because the `RETURN` clause is using `rec.title` as one of the [aggregation grouping keys](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/functions/aggregating/).

Comment: In fact a movie can have multiple Genres. does this make distinct required?

Comment: The assumption is that there be at most one `IN_GENRE` relationship to each *distinct* `Genre`. I have updated my answer to state that, which is hopefully clearer. It is OK for a movie to have multiple genres.